# How to distinguish between Thermistor, Varistor and disk capacitor?

Tags: resistors, power-electronics, electrical

How to distinguish between Thermistor, Varistor and disk capacitor they usually look the same.

Is there any way to distinguish between the three? What are some ways I could do that?

Comment: If you are doing repairs, the position in the circuit typically makes it fairly obvious, especially with appearance hints.

Comment: Simple. If the datasheet says it's a capacitor, then it most certainly is. Same for the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**APPEARANCE**

Start by visiting Google Images (images.google.com) and study the differences in appearance.

- I think *varistors* are often bright blue or red, and usually glossy, though I don't know if that is a standard.  I often notice one of the leads showing through the case for varistors.
- *Thermistors* on google images are often black.
- *Disk capacitor*s are often a dull tan/orange with no gloss.

**MARKINGS**

- Capacitors usually start with a 3-digit number like "104" (100nf or 0.1uF), but might have some other markings that indicate other characteristics.
- Common kinds of *thermistor* are "NTC" (negative temperature coefficient) and "PTC" ("positive temperature coefficient) types.  I notice that many of the images on google have NTC at the top of the markings.  It might be the same with PTC's.

You can try googling markings that you don't understand; you might find what they mean.

**MEASUREMENT**

- A *disk capacitor* can be measured on a DMM that has a capacitance range.
- *Thermistors* can be measured on a resistance range.  Measure it, apply heat, and measure again; the resistance should change.
- *Varistors* often have a very high resistance and may show up as "open circuit" or "over range".

You can google on varistor or thermistor testing or measuring to learn more about what they should look when measured.  Understanding the different purposes and constructions of the components will help, too.

Answer (score 1):

> How to distinguish between Thermistor, Varistor and disk capacitor
>   they usually looks the same...

The best practice is know what you buy and keep items packaged up separately then you don't need to try and distinguish item A from item B. If you are trying to recover items from an unknown PCB i.e. you are hoping to salvage used (and possibly broken) components then my advice is this.....

Don't waste your time trying to save a few pennies because, almost certainly you will waste more value in lost time than money saved. Buy new items and look after them.

Comment: There are two kinds of experimenters: those who can afford to buy everything new and time is money (tend to be professionals), and those who cannot, or relish salvage (tend to be non-professional / experimenters).

Comment: @MarkColan my advice does not distinguish between either. Pro's do usually always buy so my advice (above) is wasted on them because they know it already. That leaves non-pro's and, given the cheapness of the components mentioned in the question, there is no argument for buying and not scavenging around.

Comment: Cheap is one thing.  Having to pay huge shipping fees, and the delay of getting the part, is another.  To each their own.  As for me, I like finding useful things in salvage.

Comment: Moreover, it is useful to be able to look at a part and know what it is - and is not.